# Order of Bonding in Nonaqeuous Hydrated Salts

Tags: bond, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

In the chemical formula of a hydrated salt, such as $\ce{CuSO_4.5H_2O}$, is it implied from the format of the name that the the Copper (II) ion is ionically bonded to the sulfate, with water molecules surrounding both, or that the Copper (II) ion forms a coordination complex with 6 water molecules and the complex ion bonds with the sulfate ion?

I think that in the case of copper (II) sulfate, there indeed is a complex ion formed, otherwise, how could there be the blue color? I thought that the convention for this kind of nomenclature was to use the dot for the first case, and then use $\ce{[Cu(H_2O)_5]SO_4}$ when there is a complex ion involved. Thus, isn't the better name for Copper (II) sulfate, $\ce{[Cu(H_2O)_5]SO_4}$?

*Update: It seems from the comments that in this case, Copper (II) sulfate is better described by the second naming type. Are there any transition metal salts that fit the first description: where it is a normal ionic bond except with water surrounding the cation and anion?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38864/hydrates-in-aqueous-solutions

Comment: As for the name, the current one is better, for people are used to it; but if you want your formula to be as _factually correct_ as possible, write it as $\ce{[Cu(H_2O)_4]SO_4.H2O}$ (which nobody normally writes like that, but... whatever).

Comment: The bond in $\ce{CuSO_4.5H_2O}$, if anything, **is** indeed a normal ionic bond.